# Question has a tag that doesn't show up in edit

Tags: bug, tags, user-interface

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19346206/how-to-move-a-map-under-a-marker) question is showing [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) among the tags under the question as well as in the title on the browser tab. But, when I click the edit button, and see tags, that section doesn't show [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) among the tags.

PS. I wanted to remove the [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) tag, because the question, all its answers, related code, examples, and linked questions are related to Android only, and it doesn't have any relation to iOS.

PPS. This is tested on Chrome/Win10 and Chrome/Win8. Problem persists on both systems.

**Update:**

@TheLittleNaruto removed the tag. Please check the answer below for information about how he did it. I am not sure, if that hack has uncovered another bug, or it is just a part of the same bug.

Comment: I explicitly tried to remove the [tag:ios] tag when I edited the question. My other edits went through, but removing the tag didn't. (I'm using Chrome on a Mac.)

Comment: Repro'd in FF on Android N

Comment: most weird thing is that the ios tag isn't in SEDE: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/918551

Answer (score 9):

For now I fixed this issue. I had to remove iOS tag and add it at the end. And then again I edited and removed it.

Comment: Another victim of caching.