# Why is this question shown with a tag (dart) it doesn't have?

Tags: bug, status-review, tags, questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74154474/2711488) is shown to me as having the [dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dart) tag, despite it isn’t tagged with [dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dart) (and never was), as can seen in the history or when trying to edit the tags.

##### [When just browsing to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74154474/2711488)

[image: Normal question view showing “dart” tag]

##### When editing the tags

[image: Tag editor not showing “dart” tag]

##### When showing [the history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74154474/revisions)

[image: Last part of “revisions”]

Comment: This is a fun bug. [This report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217797) looks to be the same issue, with caching suggested as the culprit. For some reason that report has been marked as [status-norepro]. I can confirm the one you've reported at least.

Comment: Probably same issue as [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375950/question-showing-a-tag-which-doesnt-show-up-in-edit). I believe I've seen more topics on this in the past. Long story short: the rendered post is stored separately and for some reason is out of sync with its source. Editing the tags updates/re-renders it and resolves the issue. (If this is in fact the same issue.)

Comment: Another case [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418381/this-question-appears-to-have-an-unremovable-tag).

Comment: @Ivar that seems to be the closest match so far. Not only does it describe the same behavior regarding edit (“the tag does not appear when trying to edit”), it also has in common that the tag is so unrelated that the mod’s theory (“the tag was added and removed during grace period”) is rather implausible.

Comment: Maybe if nobody edits it to "fix" the tags this time someone can figure out why this happens.

Comment: Even looking at the wayback machine, it shows no edits between the dart tag existing on it and the dart tag not existing a day later

Comment: @KevinB the wayback machine is highly unlikely to catch an edit made and removed during a grace period

Comment: @KarlKnechtel seems like edits removed in the grace periods are still in the revision history. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/421274/revisions). I added the word "test" at the end of the answer and then immediately edited to remove it. Now it says there is entry for revision #2 which says "[Edit removed during grace period]". [Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kNLe.png) in case the revision history changes. Although, I did wait out the grace period time before checking the history - just in case entry #2 was removed after the grace period but it wasn't.

Comment: I've made some rookie SEDE queries that found ~60 other questions that seem to have this bug. [they can be found on my MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383668/997587).

Answer (score 11):

This is bizarre. The question itself does show four tags including [dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dart). The history does not show [dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dart) ever existing. Checking SEDE I have observed the same thing: [in Posts the table shows the tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1664630) while in [PostHistory](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1664631) it does not.

However, looking at the Wayback Machine shows something that might help narrow down the problem:

- [The snapshot from Monday 24th of October 2022](https://web.archive.org/web/20221024064011/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74154474/optimizations-of-operand-for-strings-in-jdk-17) does not have the [dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dart) in the question.
- [The snapshot from Wednesday 26th of October 2022](https://web.archive.org/web/20221026064909/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74154474/optimizations-of-operand-for-strings-in-jdk-17) **does** have the tag.

There is no snapshot from the 25th of October 2022. So, at the very least this will narrow down the time window when the tag mysteriously appeared.

Comment: The [dart] tag also appears in [PostTags](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1665052?postid=74154474) so it's not _just_ an issue with the the Posts table.

Comment: It was used as an audit on the 24th and we know that if you have tag filters set on an audit, it pretends to have one of your filtered tags. Perhaps the system has stopped pretending and started adding for real.

Comment: @RobertLongson That was my initial thought and seems most likely. But it doesn't explain the other two reports linked in the comments - those questions never had any review audits (the much older report had audits but they only occurred after the issue was notiiced and fixed). But I can't think of anything else that would be modifying the tags like that.

Comment: @animuson I noticed a very similar bug today on a different SO post and [reported it on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383668/997587). I didn't know about this MSO post before. Weirdly similar timeline: became hot network question, then got retag-only edit, then got used as a review audit. Also happened to be a ghost [tag:dart] tag.

Comment: @RobertLongson _"Perhaps the system has stopped pretending..."_ Why did that sound a little too scary? :-D

Comment: @animuson: We had another instance of a phantom [dart] tag leading to a user editing to remove a tag (which was actually [integer-arithmetic], not [dart], the question had never been tagged with [dart]) - [Compiler optimizations may cause integer overflow. Is that okay?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74102654), and see the latest comments under the question.